# Calling the httppost method is not invoked "400 Bad request is showing"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to create a simple web api project which I want to post a json to my action method which is post. But unfortunately I get 400 bad reguest with post man and I cannot even hit the action by visiting the end point.

Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

```
 [Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Question")]
[ApiController]
public class QuestionController : ControllerBase
{
    // POST api/question
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Question question)
    {

    }
}
```

https://localhost:44325/api/question this is how I call the method, and I get an error of 405 is the browser and 400 bad request in postman.

also, this is the error that I get in post man.

```
{
"errors": {
    "": [
        "A non-empty request body is required."
    ]
},
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "80000034-0005-fd00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
  }
```

Question model

```
    public class Question
    }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
From the Angular side when i make the api call it works, however when i make the postman/browser call it still doesn't work.

Comment: And how are you calling it?

Comment: Along with _how_ you're calling it, it would be useful to see `Question`, especially around any validation attributes it might contain.

Comment: https://localhost:44325/api/question this is how I call the method, and I get an error of 405 is the browser and 400 bad request in postman

Comment: I updated the post :)

Comment: *A non-empty request body is required.* - When you're doing it in Postman, what's the body you're sending look like?

Comment: Apologies, forgot to say that. I was sending json but it was empty actually. Not I added {"text":"test"} and not the error that I get is Could not get any response

Comment: Show the declaration of `Question`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen do you mean the implementation of that model? is above, I updated the question with the model as well.

Comment: @CsibiNorbert what is your controller base?

Comment: What is the request from angular? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Have you enabled `AntiforgeryToken` validation? Try to append `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` on the action.